# The editor margin left to the line numbers disappears in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

The editor margin left to the line numbers disappears in visual studio code.

I don't know how to reproduce this bug. In my desktop, I always can't add breakpoints for .py .js or another kind of files by click the editor margin. But in my laptop, everything is good.

I have tried to reinstall vs code in my desktop, but can't solve it. :-(

Answer (score 7):

You probably have `"editor.glyphMargin": false` somewhere either in user settings or workspace settings. Change it to `true` to show the margin again.

Comment: Thanks for @Rob Lourens, solve it by change setting to: `"editor.glyphMargin": true`!

Comment: I wanted to intentionally remove this margin, and this showed me how to do so. Thanks!